# How to pass different parameters to ng-submit from different submit buttons?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

Using AngularJs, I have a web page where I have three buttons to call a method. Each button currently has its own ng-click attribute, and calls the same method but passes a different parameter:

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="main.save(131)" title="Set Ready to Ship" class="btn btn-primary btn-header" ng-disabled="!main.allowedToShip || main.isLoading" ng-show="main.allowedToShip">
    <span class="icon-truck icon"></span>
</button>

<button type="submit" ng-click="main.save(132)" title="Set in Use" class="btn btn-primary btn-header" ng-disabled="!main.allowedInUse || main.isLoading" ng-show="main.allowedInUse">
    <span class="icon-meter icon"></span>
</button>

<button type="submit" ng-click="main.save(130)" title="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-header" ng-disabled="!main.allowedModify || main.isLoading">
    <span class="icon-floppy-disk icon"></span>
</button>
```

I have made a form on that page, and I want to have the buttons to use the ng-submit of the form instead of their current ng-click method. However, I don't know how I can pass the correct parameters to the ng-submit. I feel like I'm missing an obvious solution. Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: if you add `<input type="submit" style="display:none">` and in your existing  `main.save()` function, you can trigger click on this submit button

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.

How do I pass a parameter to the main.save() function from each button? I know how to make a form and create a button to submit it, but I need to know how I can have each button pass a different parameter to the main.save() function (which is the ng-submit function for the form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your 3 buttons, instead of passing a parameter, set a `$scope.someVariable` with the value (which will be different for the 3 button clicks)...

Afterwards, in the submit function running as a result of `<input type="submit" style="display:none">` click... you can process this `$scope.someVariable`